# Implementing react-tridi 360 product viewer in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I've been looking for a good 360 product viewer library and I came across react-tridi. According to the library documentation you need to simply insert a `<Tridi/>` component and pass in some props. The issue that I'm facing, however, is the that I'm getting a "window not defined" error message. I read that this is due to Server Side Rendering where window is not available. As a workaround I've tried to use Next Dynamic in the following way but I still can't make it work.

```
import React from "react";
import Tridi from "react-tridi";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(
  () => {
    return <Tridi location="../public/spin" format="jpg" count="120" />;
  },
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);

function Collection() {
return (
<div className="w-96">
        {" "}
        <DynamicComponentWithNoSSR />
      </div>
)
}
```

Comment: That's not dynamically importing the component, though, the syntax is a bit off. Try `const DynamicComponentWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import('react-tridi'), { ssr: false });`, remove `import Tridi from "react-tridi";`, and call the component with `<Tridi location="../public/spin" format="jpg" count="120" />` inside `Collection`. See  https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssrfor for further details.

Comment: Do you mean naming the const Tridi instead of DynamicComponentWithNoSSR and then calling <Tridi/> inside Collection? I tried that and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Not just renaming, replace it with the code I provided, and also removing `import Tridi from "react-tridi";` at the top of the file too.